# Are Variances generally stable for any given instrument?

Tags: variance, mean-variance

My hesitation, as I look at getting into forecasting based on observed variances, is the nagging question - if variances are not constant per-instrument, is it any good to use the last month or year's variance to predict this year's ?

If variances are constant(ish), then my follow-up is - what is the causal model that predicts why this is so? I'm uncomfortable without a mental model of why one stock should have variance distinct from another one, and I want to have some sense of how to know the likeliness of a sudden increase of variance, which would be very bad news indeed!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Variances are definitely not constantt, they fluctuate both for market-wide reasons and (to a lesser extent) for reasons specific to each stock

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are exactly asking. But usually even a simple Garch(1,1) would be the naive approach of forecasting variance using last period's variance.
A very good survey of volatility modelling on the Arch/garch family is the [Hansen and Lunde 2005](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jae.800/abstract).

They show that hardly one can beat a garch(1,1), so that is a good first guess.